# Getting Master Page Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, controls, root, master-pages

I'm looking for a way to access my page's controls.

I found this function that allows me to enter the ID of my control and the "root control"
and than it searches the children of the "root control" untill it finds my control id.

But the problem is that my control is nested in a table and the table is nested in a page in my master page.

whats the root control for the master page?

Comment: Sorry question is not that clear.  Master page cannot contain a page.  A page refers to a master page.  If you are trying to find a control in the master page from a page, simply pass this.Master as your root control id.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`Master`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.master.aspx) property of your content page to get the master page, then 
`FindControl` to drill down till you get the control you are looking for (or you can use the function you already have).

See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xxwa0ff0.aspx) howto on MSDN.

Answer (score 0):

Try

(this.Page.MasterPage as MyMasterPage).SomeMasterPageMethodOrProperty